# Who implemented the IEEE 855 MOSI (Microprocessor Operating System Interfaces) standard?

Tags: standards

IEEE 855 – Standard for Microprocessor Operating Systems Interfaces (MOSI) – defines a standard API for use with microcomputer operating systems. Publication timeline:

- First edition ([IEEE 855-1985](https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/855/1258/)), approved by IEEE board in March 1985, published in December 1985
- Second edition ([IEEE 855-1990](https://standards.ieee.org/ieee/855/1259/), doi:10.1109/IEEESTD.1990.94608), approved by IEEE board in May 1990, published in October 1990, approved by ANSI in November 1990, withdrawn in April 1996

It was produced by IEEE's Microprocessor Standards Committee (MSC, established 1976), which is still around and responsible for more enduring standards such as IEEE 754 floating point.

I have a copy of IEEE 855. Its API is divided into chapters (Memory Management, Time Management, Data Transfer, Data Management, etc). Each chapter is subdivided into modules. Generally speaking, module 1 represents basic functionality in that area, subsequent modules define more advanced functions. For example, the first chapter to define APIs, chapter 3 (Memory Management), contains Module 1 (Simple Memory Management) which defines API calls `ALLOCATE_MEMORY`, `FREE_MEMORY`, `GET_ALLOCATION_UNIT`, `GET_AMOUNT_REMAINING`, `GET_BLOCK_SIZE`; and Module 2 (Multispace Memory Management) which defines API calls `MAKE_POOL`, `FREE_POOL`, `ALLOCATE_FROM_POOL`, `GET_GLOBAL_MEMORY_ID`, `GET_STORAGE_ID`.

The standard provides an abstract description of the parameters and semantics of each API call, but it is up to language bindings (defined in the appendices, for Pascal, C, FORTRAN 77, COBOL 85, Ada 83 and Intel PL/M-86) to map that abstract description to the syntax of each language. To give an example, `MAKE_POOL` is abstractly defined as (p. 22):

```
MAKE_POOL (size, attributes, pool-number, parameters) ({pool-id}, amount, error)
```

The Pascal binding maps that to (p. 139):

```
procedure OsMkPol {MAKE_POOL}
    (   Size: LongInteger;
        Attributes: Integer;
        PoolNumber: LongInteger;
        Parameters: OsMessage;
    var PoolId: Systemtag;
    var Amount: LongInteger;
    var EB: ErrorBlock);
```

The C binding is (p. 159):

```
systag_t osmkpol /* MAKE_POOL */
    (long size, int attributes, long pool_number,
        storid_t parameters, long *amount_p, error_t *error_p);
```

The FORTRAN 77 binding does not include memory management chapter, on the grounds that "FORTRAN does not support the concept of dynamic allocation of memory or data items" (page 184). This is an example of how some of the language bindings do not include the whole standard. Memory management is, for the same basic reason, omitted from the COBOL binding (page 197). Another example is that the Pascal binding omits the Simple Memory Management `ALLOCATE_MEMORY` call, on the grounds that native Pascal facilities are equivalent.

The Ada binding maps `MAKE_POOL`, not to a single procedure, but to two separate ones (p. 212):

```
procedure MAKE_VARIABLE_POOL (
    SIZE: in OS_LONG_NATURAL;
    ATTRIBUTES: in POOL_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE;
    POOL_NUMBER: in OS_LONG_INTEGER;
    PARAMETERS: in OS_DATA_BLOCK,
    POOL_ID: out SYSTEMTAG,
    AMOUNT: out OS_LONG_NATURAL);
procedure MAKE_FIXED_POOL (
    SIZE: in OS_LONG_NATURAL;
    ATTRIBUTES: in POOL_ATTRIBUTES_TYPE;
    POOL_NUMBER: in OS_LONG_INTEGER;
    BLOCK_SIZE: in OS_LONG_INTEGER;
    PARAMETERS : in OS_DATA_BLOCK,
    POOL_ID: out SYSTEMTAG;
    AMOUNT: out OS_LONG_NATURAL);
```

The PL/M binding (p. 230):

```
MAKE_POOL:
    PROCEDURE (SIZE, ATTRIBUTES, POOL$NUMBER,
        PARAMETERS, AMOUNT$P, ERROR$P)
        SYSTEMTAG EXTERNAL;
    DECLARE SIZE LONG_INTEGER,
        ATTRIBUTES INTEGER,
        POOL$NUMBER LONG_INTEGER,
        PARAMETERS STORAGEID,
        AMOUNT$P INTEGER,
        ERROR$P POINTER;
    END;
```

An August 1984 paper (Jackson, D., & Cowan, J. (1984). The Proposed IEEE 855 Microprocessor Operating Systems Interface Standard. IEEE Micro, 4(4), 63–71. [doi:10.1109/mm.1984.291221](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/mm.1984.291221)) describes it, and mentions that the paper's coauthors, both Motorola employees, were the current and previous chairs of the IEEE 855 working group.

Implementations of which I am aware:

- 1991 conference paper (M. Stephan, U. Hacker, K. Henn, A. Richert, K. Sobotta and A. Weinert, "The COSY control system, a distributed realtime operating system: first practical experience at the COSY-injector," Conference Record of the 1991 IEEE Particle Accelerator Conference, 1991, pp. 1362-1364 vol.3, [doi:10.1109/PAC.1991.164636](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/PAC.1991.164636)) reports development of a real-time operating system with MOSI as its API ("RT/OS"). The anonymous FTP site `cecs.cc.kfa-juelich.de` is given as a reference for RT/OS, but it is no longer accessible, and I'm not aware of any mirrors of it. A [2019 blog post](https://protonvda.com/2019/07/30/progress-of-the-machine-control-upgrade-at-cosy-julich/) gives the impression they may still be using it as part of the control system for their particle accelerator (although the blog post is not entirely clear on that point).
- SIG/M Volume 253 contains James D. Mooney (West Virginia University)'s 1985 implementation of MOSI for CP/M-80 and Pascal/MT+. I have [uploaded it to GitHub](https://github.com/skissane/MOSI).

Does anyone know of any other implementations?

Comment: I think I remember 855 in part due the (C/I)[TRON Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRON_project), but can't find any references online. This would make it a quite up to date usage.